# Exception: Correlation failed when trying to login with Microsoft

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-server-side

After following the docs on how to add Microsoft Account login from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/microsoft-logins?view=aspnetcore-5.0), I am getting the following exception. There are a bunch of other questions regarding this issue but none of the solutions have worked for me.

I am using the default Identity implementation (individual user accounts at project creation).

[image: Exception Image]

**Startup.cs:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddBlazorise(options =>
        {
            options.ChangeTextOnKeyPress = true; // optional
        })
        .AddBootstrapProviders()
        .AddFontAwesomeIcons();

        services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("ASPIdentityDB")));

        services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserDbContext>();

        services.AddAuthentication().AddMicrosoftAccount(options =>
        {
            options.ClientId = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientId"];
            options.ClientSecret = Configuration["Authentication:Microsoft:ClientSecret"];
        });

        services.AddRazorPages();
        services.AddServerSideBlazor();
        services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<ApplicationUser>>();
        services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

        services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

        services.AddResponseCompression(opts =>
        {
            opts.MimeTypes = ResponseCompressionDefaults.MimeTypes.Concat(
                new[] { "application/octet-stream" });
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IUserIdProvider, NameUserIdProvider>();
        services.AddSignalR();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseResponseCompression();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllers();
            endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
    }
```

**Azure configuration:**
[image: Azure configuration]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in my case was to add this simple cookie policy:

```
app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions()
            {
                HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.Always,
                Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always,
                MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None
            });
```